# Is there an equivalent to PrepareDataContext in EF Core 2 or is this no longer required?

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I am converting from LinqToSQL to Entity Framework Core 2. While converting some methods I realized I am not sure if the ***PrepareDataContext*** are required any more. I am more generally asking if there's an equivalent in EFC2. I cannot find a massive amount of information on this.

For some tangible reference here is a snippet of the code I am looking at.

```
Protected Overrides Sub PrepareDataContext(ByVal pobjContext As DbDataContext)
        MyBase.PrepareDataContext(pobjContext)

        Dim loadOptions = New System.Data.Linq.DataLoadOptions

        pobjContext.LoadOptions = loadOptions
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PrepareDataContext` must be a method of your own, it's not part of LINQ-to-SQL's `DataContext`. What matters is that the method is used to set `context.LoadOptions`. That's not possible/necessary in Entity Framework.

For one of its functions, `LoadWith`, `DataLoadOptions` is replaced by `Include`. `Include` is on a per-query basis, not per context, as `DataLoadOptions`.

For the other `DataLoadOptions` functions there's no direct alternative.

Side note: I assume that the code in your question is not your actual code. It wouldn't make much sense to add `New System.Data.Linq.DataLoadOptions` to a context without doing anything with it.

Comment: You're correct, it was just an example of something similar I saw in a portion of code. Thank you for this knowledge and explanation!